# Zach KLT : suspend tracking

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I'm trying [C.Zach implementation of the KLT feature tracking](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/chzach/opensource.html).

What I want to do is to suspend the tracking during a few frames then just restart it again **without** redetecting the features.

So I basically don't call the `advanceFrame()` method of the tracker when I want to suspend, then call `track()` when I want to start again.

It seems that all is fine, the textures used for tracking are not swapped, the only problem is the tracker does not recognize any feature in the new image (very close to the one before the suspend).

Oh and I use OpenCV to manipulate the frames but that shouldn't be an issue.

Anyone have some hints about how to do that or where the problem could come from ?